# ANTLR4 very slow, the SLL trick didn't change anything

Tags: python-3.x, antlr4

I have a grammar that is an extension of Python grammar. And small programs parse about 2 seconds on a Macbook Pro. I have taken the SLL trick and applied it:

```
  # Set up the lexer
  inputStream = InputStream(s)
  lexer = CustomLexer(inputStream)
  stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)

  # Set up the error handling stuff
  error_handler = CustomErrorStrategy()
  error_listener = CustomErrorListener()
  buffered_errors = BufferedErrorListener()
  error_listener.addDelegatee(buffered_errors)

  # Set up the fast parser
  parser = PythonQLParser(stream)
  parser._interp.predictionMode = PredictionMode.SLL
  parser.removeErrorListeners()
  parser.errHandler = BailErrorStrategy()

  try:
    tree = parser.file_input()
    return (tree,parser)
```

But it didn't do the trick, the time didn't change significantly. Any hints on what to do?

I'm using Python3 with antlr4-python3-runtime-4.5.3

The grammar file is here: [Grammar File](https://github.com/pavelvelikhov/pythonql/blob/master/src/PythonQL.g4)

And the project github page is here: [Github](https://github.com/pavelvelikhov/pythonql)

I have also ran a profiler, here are significant entries from the parser:

```
    ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    21    0.000    0.000    0.094    0.004 PythonQLParser.py:7483(argument)
    8    0.000    0.000    0.195    0.024 PythonQLParser.py:7379(arglist)  
    9    0.000    0.000    0.196    0.022 PythonQLParser.py:6836(trailer)  
    5/3    0.000    0.000    0.132   0.044 PythonQLParser.py:6765(testlist_comp)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.012    0.012 PythonQLParser.py:6154(window_end_cond)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.057    0.057 PythonQLParser.py:6058(sliding_window)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.057    0.057 PythonQLParser.py:5941(window_clause)
    1   0.000    0.000    0.004   0.004 PythonQLParser.py:5807(for_clause_entry)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.020 0.020 PythonQLParser.py:5752(for_clause) 
    2/1   0.000   0.000   0.068   0.068 PythonQLParser.py:5553(query_expression)    
   48/10    0.000    0.000    0.133    0.013 PythonQLParser.py:5370(atom) 
    48/7    0.000    0.000    0.315    0.045 PythonQLParser.py:5283(power) 
    48/7    0.000    0.000    0.315    0.045 PythonQLParser.py:5212(factor) 
    48/7    0.000    0.000    0.331    0.047 PythonQLParser.py:5132(term) 
    47/7    0.000    0.000    0.346    0.049 PythonQLParser.py:5071(arith_expr) 
    47/7    0.000    0.000    0.361    0.052 PythonQLParser.py:5010(shift_expr) 
    47/7    0.000    0.000    0.376    0.054 PythonQLParser.py:4962(and_expr) 
    47/7    0.000    0.000    0.390    0.056 PythonQLParser.py:4914(xor_expr) 
    47/7    0.000    0.000    0.405    0.058 PythonQLParser.py:4866(expr) 
    44/7    0.000    0.000    0.405    0.058 PythonQLParser.py:4823(star_expr) 
    43/7    0.000    0.000    0.422    0.060 PythonQLParser.py:4615(not_test) 
    43/7    0.000    0.000    0.438    0.063 PythonQLParser.py:4563(and_test) 
    43/7    0.000    0.000    0.453    0.065 PythonQLParser.py:4509(or_test) 
    43/7    0.000    0.000    0.467    0.067 PythonQLParser.py:4293(old_test) 
    43/7    0.000    0.000    0.467    0.067 PythonQLParser.py:4179(try_catch_expr)
    43/7    0.000    0.000    0.482    0.069 PythonQLParser.py:3978(test) 
    1    0.000    0.000    0.048    0.048 PythonQLParser.py:2793(import_from) 
    1    0.000    0.000    0.048    0.048 PythonQLParser.py:2702(import_stmt) 
    7    0.000    0.000    1.728    0.247 PythonQLParser.py:2251(testlist_star_expr) 
    4    0.000    0.000    1.770    0.443 PythonQLParser.py:2161(expr_stmt) 
    5    0.000    0.000    1.822    0.364 PythonQLParser.py:2063(small_stmt) 
    5    0.000    0.000    1.855    0.371 PythonQLParser.py:1980(simple_stmt) 
    5    0.000    0.000    1.859    0.372 PythonQLParser.py:1930(stmt) 
    1    0.000    0.000    1.898    1.898 PythonQLParser.py:1085(file_input)
    176    0.002    0.000    0.993    0.006 Lexer.py:127(nextToken)
    420    0.000   0.000   0.535   0.001 ParserATNSimulator.py:1120(closure)
   705    0.003    0.000    1.642    0.002 ParserATNSimulator.py:315(adaptivePredict)
```

The PythonQL program that I was parsing is this one:

```
# This example illustrates the window query in PythonQL

from collections import namedtuple
trade = namedtuple('Trade', ['day','ammount', 'stock_id'])

trades = [ trade(1, 15.34, 'APPL'),
           trade(2, 13.45, 'APPL'),
           trade(3, 8.34,  'APPL'),
           trade(4, 9.87,  'APPL'),
           trade(5, 10.99, 'APPL'),
           trade(6, 76.16, 'APPL') ]

# Maximum 3-day sum

res = (select win
        for sliding window win in ( select t.ammount for t in trades )
        start at s when True
        only end at e when (e-s == 2))

print (res)
```

Comment: The profiler shows pretty much all the time is spent in an number of PythonQLParser methods

Comment: Can you upload your grammar and code for parsing? If it's deep expression in your case (big count of same expressions like [this](https://gist.github.com/KvanTTT/bf20f6a4aac708b49df2)) you can transofrm left-recursion rules to primitive left-recursion.

Comment: @KvanTTT Hi, the grammar is here: https://github.com/pavelvelikhov/pythonql/blob/master/src/PythonQL.g4 , yes, getting huge counts of a number of rules, but I thought I did the right thing with primitive left recursion... although now I have some doubts. The additions to the Python3 grammar are these rules: path_step, try_catch_expr and query_expression

Comment: This small code sample in quetion parsed for a more than 1 sec?

Comment: @KvanTTT Yes, that tiny piece of code!

Comment: Does lexer stage fast? It's slow only for parser?

Comment: @KvanTTT So the profiler says that Lexer ate up 1 second, and the parser ate another second

Comment: The additions to the Python grammar include quite a bit of keywords right in the grammar productions. I have gone through the exercise of moving them all to the lexer, but that gave me about a 10% performance improvement only.

Comment: @randomsurfer_123: I have too little time to help, however 1) your 1st bit of code "# Set up the lexer" etc. seems incomplete - my python rejected it. 2) Perhaps try just lexing with all unicode chars commented out, so just accepts ascii - makes any difference? 3) could you tag the cols in the profile trace with their meanings (and fix the 2 unwrapped lines).

Comment: @user3779002 Hi, the full code of the preprocessor is here: https://github.com/pavelvelikhov/pythonql/blob/master/src/pythonql/parser/Preprocessor.py . Will fix the profile output, sure. I have used a parser with a bunch of unicode before, as long as its in the lexer, it seemed to work fine, but I'll try, thanks for the hint

Comment: I've had similar issues with ANTLR parsers over time, one big help was to set the "memoize=true" flag for the grammar. But I'm not sure if an equivalent still exists with Antlrv4.

Comment: @YannTM memoize has been removed from ANTLR4...

Comment: Folks, PythonQL will become a reference implementation, so please forget about this complaint, it is no longer serious

Comment: @randomsurfer_123 Some links in the posts are not available now. Please check.

Comment: @randomsurfer_123 Which profiler did you use?

Comment: The full code of the preprocessor is here: https://github.com/pythonql/pythonql/blob/master/pythonql/parser/Preprocessor.py . I think I used the pdb profiler

Comment: Wondering if this is still an issue with the Python runtime. I would like to switch the project back to Antlr